# How to change the encoding of a Process's Standard Input in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, input, encoding, process

I am trying to write to the Standard Input of a Process (a C++ program) in C#. The problem is that the C++ program seems to not be able to read what I write from my C# app. Here are both of the programs:

```csharp
// C#
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

    Process CoutN = new Process();
    CoutN.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Vesk\Desktop\CoutN.exe";
    CoutN.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    CoutN.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    CoutN.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

    CoutN.Start();
    CoutN.StandardInput.WriteLine("5");

    CoutN.WaitForExit();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

```cpp
// C++
int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << "N is " << n << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output from my C# program: `N is 0`. It should instead be `N is 5`.

From what I could understand the encoding that C# uses for a Process's Input/Output Stream is the same as the one used by the Console. Here's the thing though, in my C# program I'll need to be able to use the Console to input cyrillic text (as well as other non-ASCII text). The only Console Encoding which seems to work for that is `Encoding.Unicode` (which apparently is just UTF-16 LE).

But it seems that when I try to write to the Process's Input Stream, it just can't understand that and it outputs `N is 0` for some reason. From what I understand this is because UTF-16 is not compatible with ASCII (or whatever the C++ `iostream` expects).

**So is there a way to actually change the Encoding that the Process's Standard Input uses?**

**Here is what I have tried/cannot try:**

- I don't want to change the Console's Encoding, because I plan on running the Process in an asynchronously running method and I want to still be able to interface with the C# program, so I fear that it will mess things up, even if I just change the Encoding, only while writing to the Process and then change it back again.
- I know that the C++ program could probably be changed so that it can read UTF-16, but I don't want to do that since my C# program will have to be able to run and "interface" with all kinds of C++ programs, which use the simple `iostream` (`cin`, `cout`). (**Edit for clarification:** My C# program will only ever need to "send" ASCII text to the C++ program)
- I did try to Change the Console's Encoding to `Encoding.ASCII` and it worked. It also worked if I just left the Console at it's default Encoding. But again this will not work for me, because these encodings don't seem to work with Cyrillic.
- I tried setting the Console's Input Encoding to `Encoding.UTF8` and that didn't work, although I wouldn't have been able to use that anyway, because it doesn't seem to work with Cyrillic text in my C# app.
- I tried to change `CoutN.StandardInput.Encoding`, but unfortunately it is a read-only property.
- I tried to also redirect the Standard Output, just to see if it works, and weirdly enough it does. I can just use `CoutN.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` and it works and the output from the C++ program is read correctly (still says `N is 0` though). But for some reason the Standard Input is different.
- I tried to just not redirect the Standard Input, again just to see if it works, and again very weirdly it did!. I just wrote `5` in the C# program's Console and the output was `N is 5`.
- I tried to create a `StreamWriter` with a different encoding and write from there:

```csharp
StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter(CoutN.StandardInput.BaseStream, Encoding.ASCII);
str.WriteLine("5");
```

But this didn't work either. I even tried basically all the Encodings and even no Encoding, but nothing worked.

- I tried writing to the `BaseStream` myself:

```csharp
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("5");
CoutN.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
CoutN.StandardInput.WriteLine();
```

And that didn't work.

**At this point I feel like I've exhausted all the options that I could try. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!**

Comment: STD Input and Output are streams, they have no encoding. Encodings apply when *applications* convert the bytes they read from streams into text. And since Windows is a Unicode OS and .NET strings are Unicode, there shouldn't be any reason to change things. Definitely not using the 7-bit US-ASCII codepage that can't even handle all English text

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your comment, but the reason to change things in my program is because it is simply not working. From what I read on the C# Documentation, a Process's Standard Input, does have an encoding, but maybe I just didn't understand it correctly.

Comment: The problem is in the C++ code, not C#. You're trying to read from the standard input as if it contained single-byte text. Most likely, the program was compiled as ASCII as well instead of Unicode. Windows applications are *not* compiled this way since the late 1990s, early 2000s, precisely because the OS is Unicode and Windows is used all over the world. Working with Unicode in C++ though is tricky, because the standardization process was *very* slow. While there are `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `u16string` and `u32string` types now, there was no explicit UTF8 type until C++ 20.

Comment: I understand that but I don't want to actually send anything besides ASCII characters to my C++ program. And as I said in my post, I don't want to change the C++ program, this is just an example one and my C# app will need to made so that it can "interface" with C++ programs that use the `iostream` (`cin` and `cout`).

Comment: What you call ASCII is the 7-bit ASCII that can't even handle all English text, like `Charlotte Brontë`. It's not used by any operating system or process. Again, you're asking how to break the C# program to avoid fixing a C++ bug, that no C++ Windows application should have.

Comment: Instead of asking how to change the C# encoding, you should ask what the C++ encoding is - unless you specify one, it's the one that corresponds to the machine locale, **not ASCII**. The label in the Regional settings even says `Locale used by non-Unicode programs`. Even US machines use Latin1, not ASCII. This is exposed as `Encoding.Default` on C# programs, because that's what it is - the default encoding when dealing with non-Unicode I/O.

Comment: Long story short. Use `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Default;` or even remove that line completely. Better yet, fix the C++ bug. Using `char` and `string` on a Unicode OS is simply wrong, and the kind of bug that disappeared by 2000.

Comment: Well the thing is as far as I understand it, in C++ the "default" is this 7-bit ASCII (at least in `iostream`). I didn't mention this, because the post was already long enough, but the actual reason that I am doing this is a school project. It is a C# app that judges (simple) C++ programs for competitive programming. And as I said I don't get to choose how these C++ programs are made, but `iostream` is what almost all of them use. If I could compile the C++ code differently so that it can read Unicode from the `iostream` that would work as well, but I have no idea if that is possible.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong then. `char` is 8-bit with *absolutely no assumption* on the codepage

Comment: Also I know that what I am trying to achieve is possible, because I have seen C# programs do this. I even wrote one myself a while ago, but that was a WinForm application and since it didn't change the Console's Encoding it just worked. This time though it has to be a Console App.

Comment: Bytes are translated into text based on the environment. On Linux, the encoding comes from the `LC_` environment variables. On Windows, it's the system locale. Only the `char16_t`, `char32_t` and `char8_t` types have a specific encoding

Comment: `since it didn't change the Console's Encoding it just worked.` in this case though you *changed* the stream encoding to UTF16. If you want to use the system locale, don't change the encoding. Winforms apps are Console apps with a GUI, not a different type of OS process

Comment: Why not change the encoding to `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8`? 7-bit ASCII and UTF8 use the same byte values.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your previous comment, but to respond to them, as I said in my post I don't want to change the C# Console's Encoding as I fear that doing that even if I change it right back will mess with the rest of my program, as I will be running this Process's execution in an asynchronously running method, and I will still want to be able to Write and Read from the Console.

Comment: But you *already* changed that encoding. That's what caused the problem in the first place. It doesn't affect the rest of the program, only the `Console.Input` and `Console.Output` *StreamWriter* instances.

Comment: Yeah I tried changing it to UTF8, but it didn't work, and also my C# app couldn't read Cyrillic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232851/discussion-between-vesk-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: There's no point. Windows works with Cyrillic just fine. Windows apps written in C++ work with Cyrillic just fine. This is the very case why you *can't* use ASCII though. It's not just that there are no Cyrillic characters in ASCII. If you want to handle both Cyrillic and eg French or German text, you need a codepage that covers both Cyrillic and Latin1. Only Unicode does this.

Comment: C# applications work with Cyrillic or Greek text just fine out of the box. That's why I can write `Αυτό Εδώ` and be certain it will appear correctly. StackOverflow is an ASP.NET application without hard-coded encodings. Like all web sites, the HTML output is UTF8

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite understand what you mean. In my C# app I need to be able to read/write both Latin and Cyrillic, so I have to use `Encoding.Unicode` for the Console. But the C++ programs will use simple 8-bit chars and `iostream`, and they will only ever need to receive Latin (+ numbers etc.) characters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get to chose what encoding the other process is using from your own code - if you're sending input to the standard input stream of an application that is expecting a specific encoding, then short of it having some setting to change that there's nothing you can do about it.

If you're interacting with the STDIO streams of another application, you are expected to match whatever encoding it is expecting, rather than the other way around. The encoding of the console doesn't really matter except in cases where the application inherits its encoding from the environment.

Indeed, if you're trying to use an encoding that supports Cyrillic characters, then the receiving application must have been designed to accommodate this. If the application was written by someone whose native character set only uses Latin characters then they may well have never bothered to do this. It's part of the reason for the push to adopt UTF8 everywhere since then you don't really need to think about it too much.

Edit: If you're trying to match the expected input encoding, then you do it thusly:

```
Process.StandardInput.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("My String Here\r\n"));
```

Replacing `Encoding.ASCII` with whatever character set applies to get the appropriate `GetBytes()` method.

Note that the ASCII character set specifically does not include Cyrillic characters, so it's impossible to use them in an application that expects ASCII. If it expects some other character set that does support them then you're fine. Cyrillic uses Codepage 855 or needs UTF8.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it correctly in my post, but I do want to match the encoding that the C++ program is expecting. That is what I'm trying to do. But I can't seem to find a way to do that, without changing the encoding of the Console in my C# app. Also I only want/need to send ASCII characters to my C++ program.

Comment: @Vesk there's no ASCII even in tthe US. If you want to use the same non-Unicode encodiing as the C++ application, use `Encoding.Default`. Set `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Default`. `Encoding.Default` corresponds to the system/user locale, which in the Regional Settings GUI appears as `Locale used by non-Unicode programs`. Tthat's what your C++ application uses

Comment: @PhonicUK Sorry, accidentally clicked the checkmark.

Comment: In that case what you can do is write to the input stream directly with your own encoding. See my updated answer.